# Docker Volumes File Path not found

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume

I am creating an express js server which compiles python code and then return the output to the user.

```js
app.post("/compile", async(req, res) => {
  const {code, input} = req.body
  
  // Write the script and input files to some files
  const fileName = getFileName();
  const codeFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'code_volume', 'code', fileName);
  const inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'code_volume', 'input', fileName) + '.txt';

  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(codeFilePath, code)
    fs.writeFileSync(inputFilePath, input)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.json({error: true,
      error_message: "Oh uh, something went wrong"
    })
  }

  const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname);

  // Docker command to run the script
  let execCommand = `docker run -v ${absolutePath}${path.sep}code_volume:/code_volume python3.11`;
  execCommand += ` python /code_volume/code/${fileName} < /code_volume/input/${fileName}.txt`;


  exec(execCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.json({error: true,
        error_message: stderr
      })
    }
    return res.json({
      output: stdout
    })
  })
})
```

```
Output -> "The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n"
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error, I can see that these 2 files were created on my computer and since this was synced (volumes) to the contianer that means container should have these files as well. 
Also if from `execCommand` I remove `< /code_volume/input/${fileName}.txt` the code seems to work fine, but it wont accept any input.

What could be the problem here? can someone please help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That construction is a little scary to me.  Are you _sure_ none of those variables contain characters like spaces or semicolons that might be meaningful to the shell?  Do you know which path it's complaining about?  Can use use a Docker SDK, instead of trying to invoke the `docker` CLI tool?